# How To Post Image on twitter using post URL using Android?

Tags: android, twitter

I have tried twitter4j-core-2.1.11.jar using this jar, posting image was fine. but now i  have used apache-mime4j-0.6.jar ,httpmime-4.0.1.jar, scribe-1.3.3.jar. `Login and posting tweet as text its working` . but i `want to post image with text message` how can i post it ...
`i dont want to use twitter4j-core-2.1.11.jar`
i want to use `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json`. Please Tell ME how to post Image..

See my code bellow.

```
      public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// TWITTER SHARE VARIABLES
final static String APIKEY = "***********";
final static String APISECRET = "*******************************";
final static String CALLBACK = "http://www.google.com";
OAuthService Oathserv;
Token requestToken;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (isInternetAvailable()) {
                postStatusOnTwitter();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Internet service not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    });
}

public boolean isInternetAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null)
        return (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected() && cm
                .getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable());
    else
        return false;
}

// TWITTER SHARING START
private void postStatusOnTwitter() {

    final WebView webView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    webView1.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    webView1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                    v.requestFocus();
                }
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    // set up service and get request token as seen on scribe website
    // https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/wiki/Getting-Started

    // attach WebViewClient to intercept the callback url
    webView1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            // check for our custom callback protocol otherwise use
            // default
            // behavior
            if (url.startsWith("http")) {
                // authorization complete hide webview for now.
                webView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");

                if (verifier != null) {
                    Verifier v = new Verifier(verifier);

                    // save this token for practical use.
                    Token accessToken = Oathserv.getAccessToken(requestToken, v);








                    // host twitter detected from callback
                    // oauth://twitter
                    Log.e("Host", uri.getHost().toString());
                    if (uri.getHost().equals("www.google.com")) {
                        /*
                         * OAuthRequest req = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET,
                         * "http://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json"
                         * );
                         */
                    /*  OAuthRequest req = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST,
                                "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json");

                        req.addBodyParameter("status", "Hello Twitter");

                        Oathserv.signRequest(accessToken, req);
                        */

                        OAuthRequest req = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST,
                                "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json");

                       //   req.addBodyParameter("status", "bdf Twitter");
                        req.addBodyParameter("media[]", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz0qZ.jpg"); // here will be image 

                        Oathserv.signRequest(accessToken, req);




                        org.scribe.model.Response response = req.send();










                        try {
                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response
                                    .getBody());
                            android.util.Log.i("Twitter Response",
                                    json.toString());
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Shared on twitter successfully",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }




                    }
                }

                return true;
            }

            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    });

    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                Oathserv = new ServiceBuilder().provider(TwitterApi.class)
                        .apiKey(APIKEY).apiSecret(APISECRET)
                        .callback(CALLBACK).build();

                requestToken = Oathserv.getRequestToken();
                final String authURL = Oathserv.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken);
                // send user to authorization page
                webView1.loadUrl(authURL);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

// TWITTER SHARING END

        }
```

Comment: Hi addy i was able to post message using 1.1 but i was not able to upload image to twitter. I am using "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json" url but it is still giving response as {"errors": [{"message": "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.", "code": 68}]}

Comment: Yeah .. Me too was able to upload the image also

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue of twitter post image.

```
final ProgressDialog progress = UIHelper.showProgress(ShareWostActivity.this, "Twitter !", "Please wait ...");
final WebView webView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.showwost_webView);
webView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
webView1.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
webView1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
switch (event.getAction()) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
  if (!v.hasFocus()) {
    v.requestFocus();
  }
  break;
}
return false;
  }
});
webView1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  @Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, final String url) {
if (url.startsWith("http")) {
  // authorization complete hide webview for now.
  final Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
  final String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
  Log.i("1", "1-->" + verifier);
  if (verifier != null) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Verifier v = new Verifier(verifier);
    Token accessToken = s.getAccessToken(requestToken, v);
    // host twitter detected from callback
    // oauth://twitter
    if (uri.getHost().equals("www.google.com")) {
      try {
        OAuthRequest req = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST,
        "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json");
        s.signRequest(accessToken, req);
        File outputDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile("temp_inner_twitter", ".jpg", outputDir);
        Bitmap bitmap = createBitmap();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
        Log.i("asds", tempFile.length() + "," + tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
        bitmap.recycle();
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
        String urii = Uri.parse(createShareLink(urlwost)).toString();
        entity.addPart("status", new StringBody("Vote here ww.abc.com\n Download WO? App http://www.google.com/"));
        entity.addPart("media", new FileBody(tempFile, "image/jpeg"));
        entity.addPart("access_token", new StringBody(accessToken.getToken()));
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        entity.writeTo(out);
        req.addPayload(out.toByteArray());
        req.addBodyParameter("status", "I have uploaded test image on twitter");
        req.addHeader(entity.getContentType().getName(), entity.getContentType().getValue());
        org.scribe.model.Response response = req.send();
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.getBody());
        Log.i("Twitter Response", json.toString());
        if (!json.has("errors")) {
          Toast
          .makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image shared on twitter successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
          .show();
        } else {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error while sharing application on twitter",
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
      } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error while sharing application on twitter",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error while sharing application on twitter",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
    }
      }
    }).run();
    webView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    // save this token for practical use.
  }
  return true;
}
return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
  }
});
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
s = new ServiceBuilder().provider(TwitterApi.class).apiKey(APIKEY).apiSecret(APISECRET).callback(CALLBACK)
    .build();
requestToken = s.getRequestToken();
// send user to authorization page
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final String authURL = s.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken);
    Log.i("2", "--" + authURL);
    webView1.loadUrl(authURL);
    progress.dismiss();
  }
});
  }
}).start();
```